# Issuse encrypting a gzip compressed raw text: value change to base64

Tags: encryption, aes, gzip

I have the following raw text :

```
.
```

It represents a `gz` compressed value. Here is the raw text uncompressed :

```
.
```

Now I would like to encrypt it using AES in CBC mode with a 128 bits long key. Here are the key and the inizialization vector I'm using:

```
key:  asdfgh0123456789
iv:   0123456789asdfgh
```

Anyway when I try to decrypt the cypertext obtained from encryption I got `base64` encoded raw text as my input.

[Here][1] is the website service I'm using to encrypt and decrypt.

Why does my input change automatically to base64 ? Whats wrong ?

Screenshot :

Screenshot: [![enter image description here][2]][2]

Comment: You should also post the link to the online tool, in order for people being easily able to help you.

Comment: @GiovaLomba  link added . thanks for response

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem with a sequence of bytes is that they cannot simply be shown on a screen because you can have 256 different values on a single byte but the alphabet only has 26 different letters.

Given a sequence of bytes it can be represented in letters and numbers when converted to base64.

1) The text `TEST` is represented in bytes as `54 45 53 54` and as base64 as `VEVTVA==`

2) GZ of `TEST` is represented in bytes as `1f 8b 08 00 00 00 00 00 00 ff 0b 71 0d 0e e1 e2 02 00 cf 1b f9 1e 06 00 00 00`  and as base64 as `H4sIAAAAAAAA/wtxDQ7h4gIAzxv5HgYAAAA=`

Now you can encrypt the *bytes* of the gz or the *base64* of the gz - they are different.

When using a web page that takes text as input you better use the *base64* of the gz. Then, when you decrypt you get what you used.

Comment: I'm going to encrypt " H4sIAAAAAAAAAKtWSkkty0xODfVMUbJSSi7IT/Z0Csw29/BV0lHKLykISi0sTS0uAUqlJeYUpwIFCxKLi8vzi0CqM7LS0jMz0tOBoqXFqUUQEzISkzNK9YoTcx3ScxMzc/SS83OVagHQKGJnZgAAAA== " and get exactly the same " gdj6BojPAbmmPRr9QrKfIpUAdopmkiTXqVyVpYFDJxqcJeMZIKNynthGfBcUECuL8ZjTyXHZ9P2tkRF4Eb4/EUbJUX5q0BbkxCxQAMqDdIqMXUnW2EPLNnDWu8iK6o0gUWWY8nPP60SEXKX05GWnTA+cuXjWgHOFtBTFddG1cUY= "

but just getting same error

Comment: i can decrypt ciphetext : " https://i.imgur.com/N0OULTL.png " and decrypted is gzip compressed . it is ok .
but now im going to encrypt it with same key and iv : " https://i.imgur.com/wfh1itA.png " . but getting another ciphertext .

how i can get same ciphertext ?

Comment: Because you are using the decrypted **BASE64** bytes as the **TEXT** bytes. You need to upload a binary files (that site you are using does not have option there to input as base64 - so there is the confusion). You can generate the binary file you need here: https://gchq.github.io/CyberChef/#recipe=From_Base64('A-Za-z0-9%2B/%3D',true)&input=SDRzSUFBQUFBQUFBQUt0V1Nra3R5MHhPRGZWTVViSlNTaTdJVC9aMENzdzI5L0JWMGxIS0x5a0lTaTBzVFMwdUFVcWxKZVlVcHdJRkN4S0xpOHZ6aTBDcU03TFMwak16MHRPQm9xWEZxVVVRRXpJU2t6Tks5WW9UY3gzU2N4TXpjL1NTODNPVmFnSFFLR0puWmdBQUFBPT0

Just need click the download as file on the output

Comment: can i get cyberchef base64 encode, decode and gzip compress and decompress javascript code to Execution in another app ?

Answer (score 0):

First and foremost you have to understand that **you are not encrypting a raw text gzip**. You are actually encrypting a `base64` form of your raw text `gizp`.

Then symmetric encryption algorithms like `AES` are useful because given a cleartext and key they allows ciphering and deciphering to transform respectively your in input first in ciphertext and then cleartext.

As shown in your screenshot you correctly achieved that! *So really nothing wrong.* To return to original form of raw `gzip` text you just have to decode the output of decryption using the `base64` encoding scheme and you'll get wath you are looking for.

Moreover as you already knows not all bytes values can be represented by visible symbols,  this is the main reason often encrypted text or binary data is represented using `base64`. Over other enconding scheme, it has less overhead. For instance `hex` encoding double the input size; while instead `base64` makes it (on average) 33% bigger.

As a bonus: Here is useful tools for this kind of transformations [Cyberchef](https://gchq.github.io/CyberChef/).